# 3d parametric spiral to 3D goldean mean spiral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics, nonlinear-system, noncommutative-geometry

I know I can create a 3d parametric spiral with the formula below
but How can I do the same thing with goldean spiral?
I looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral but I don't see how to convert that formula on the page into a 3D parametric curve.

```
x=t *sin(t);
y=t *cos(t);
z=t;
```

Thanks to Narasimham I got it to work some what.  But does anyone know why it doesn't reach the zero axis?  I circled the point A which is the x,y,z coordinates in yellow and it shows up as x=1,y=0,z=1.  How can I get this to be x=0, y=0, z=0.  See image below in yellow.

[image]

Comment: With $ x=t *\sin(t);  y=t *\cos(t);   z=t;  $ you are writing a spiral on a cone. It is a line in space.
Similarly you can do a line in space:$$  x=a e^{b t}\cos(t); y=a e^{b t} \sin t ; z=a e^{b t} ;$$
Else you can choose generators connecting a point on the flat Golden Spiral to a point below say $ (0,0,-1)$, forming not a single spiral line but a surface.

Comment: @Narasimham Thanks that helps, but do you know why it doesn't reach the zero axis?  I edited the question and posted an image showing what it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on sign of $b$. Choosing $  b<0, t \rightarrow \infty$, radius $ \rightarrow 0$